# Apple Push Notification service (APNS) SIM change

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, phone-number, sim-card

Will Apple still push notifications to an iPhone device even though the SIM card and phone numbers changed?

I am developing an iPhone app (my first) that relies on Apple Push Notification service. My question is related to a scenario where a customer installs my app on his/her iPhone. If the original owner gives the iPhone to another person with my app still installed, the new owner changes the SIM and has a new number still on the same carrier. Will Apple still push notifications to the device even though the SIM card and phone numbers are different? Since I can not programmatically determine the fact that the SIM and phone number changed, how do I find out that the device now belongs to a different person and stop sending notifications.

Answer (score 2):

Push notification are not based on you sim card.
They use a unique key based on phone and app installation.

Yes the new user will receive the push notifications of the old installed app.
It's not up to you to check if the device now belongs a a different user.
The person getting rite of the iDevice should clear the device.

Detect the simcard will not help since WiFi iPad and iPod touch don't have sim cards, there is no way to detect a different user.

Comment: Thanks rckoenes. My app is only for the iPhone and I wanted it to be less restrictive, i.e. I did not want to rely on password authentication every time the app is launched to verify the same user still has the phone.